# Mockito unit testing RestTemplate

Tags: java, unit-testing, post, junit, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate `postForEntity` method to post body to an endpoint. I need help with writing test case for my code using Mockito. The return type is void but it can be changed to `Types` or `code` if needed to test. I have referred many other documentation but they are very general, I tried using them but most did not work for me as the `request` and return type are different. . Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

Here is my Java class

```
    public void postJson(Set<Type> Types){
        try {
            String oneString = String.join(",", Types);
           Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
            requestBody.put("type", oneString);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody);
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), null);
ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                    new HttpEntity<>(request, getHttpHeaders()), String.class);

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test here exactly? You don't need to test `RestTemplate`. Also, how much can your code be changed? What's the class that contains this method? Is it a Spring `Service`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito mocking restTemplate.postForEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272391/mockito-mocking-resttemplate-postforentity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the logic inside MyClass class, so you should not mock it. `RestTemplate` is a dependency inside MyClass, so this is exactly what you need to mock. In general it should look like this inside your test:

This is just a simple example. A good practice would be to check that the arguments passed to your mock equal to the expected ones. One way would be to replace `Mockito.eq()` with the real expected data. Another is to verify it separately, like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> postJson(Set<Type> Types){
            try {
                String oneString = String.join(",", Types);
               Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
                requestBody.put("type", oneString);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody);
                HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), null);
    ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                        new HttpEntity<>(request, getHttpHeaders()), String.class);
                } 
        }
        return Types;
```

You can write test for above method as follows

```
   @Mock
   RestTemplate restTemplate;

   private Poster poster;
   
   HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), getHttpHeaders());
   
   ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
   
   Mockito.verify(restTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).exchange(
       Mockito.eq(uri),
       Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
       Mockito.eq(request),
       Mockito.eq(String.class));
   
   Assert.assertEquals(result, poster.postJson(mockData));
   
   HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() {
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.add(// whatever you need to add);
       return headers;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to write a whole test as a lot of information is missing. E.g. what `Type` is.
As you did not posted the name of your class I'm just name it `MyClass` for now.
Also I'm assuming that the RestTemplate is injected via the constructor like

```
MyClass(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
```

Following is a draft for a unit test using [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/) and [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/).
I would suggest mocking the `RestTemplate`. I have to admit that this way we will not cover to test the usage of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `StringHttpMessageConverter` in our test.

So a very raw draft could look like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

class MyClassTest {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private MyClass myClass;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        myClass = new MyClass(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    void callMethod() {
        Set<Type> types = Set.of(/* one of your Types */);
        String url = "http://someUrl";
        String httpResult = "";

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.getMessageConverters()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());

        ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> request = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(url, request.capture(), String.class)).thenReturn(httpResult);

        myClass.callMethod(types, url);

        HttpEntity<String> actualHttpEntity = request.getValue();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualHttpEntity.getBody(), "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added some more code for more clarity. Please let me know if some more clarification is required. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this problem, but it requires some changes.

First of all, you have to externalize the `RestTemplate` as a bean and add converters in its initialization. This way you will get rid of not covering those converters.

```java
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jsonConverter);
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(stringConverter);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Here's the new class that contains `postJson` method. As you can see, the `url` and `restTemplate` are injected through the constructor. This way we can test different cases.

```java
public class Poster {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private String url;

    public Poster(RestTemplate restTemplate, String url) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void postJson(Set<Type> types) {
        try {
            String oneString = types.stream().map(Type::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
            requestBody.put("type", oneString);
            requestBody.put("data", "aws");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody);
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), null);

            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate
                    .postForEntity(url, new HttpEntity<>(request, getHttpHeaders()), String.class);

            int code = result.getStatusCodeValue();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }

    private HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() {
        return new HttpHeaders();
    }

}
```

And here's the test class for that method.

```java
class PosterTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String url;
    private Poster poster;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.url = "http://example.com/posturl";
        this.poster = new Poster(restTemplate, url);
    }

    @Test
    void postJson() {
        // set input, I used TreeSet just to have a sorted set
        // so that I can check the results against
        Set<Type> types = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Type::toString));
        types.add(new Type("a"));
        types.add(new Type("b"));
        types.add(new Type("c"));
        types.add(new Type("d"));
        // response entity
        ResponseEntity<String> response = ResponseEntity.ok("RESPONSE");

        // mockito mock
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(url),
                ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpHeaders.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(String.class)
        )).thenReturn(response);

        // to check the results
        Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
        requestBody.put("type", "a,b,c,d");
        requestBody.put("data", "aws");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), null);
        HttpEntity<HttpEntity<String>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, new HttpHeaders());

        // actual call
        poster.postJson(types);

        // verification
        Mockito.verify(restTemplate, times(1)).postForEntity(
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(url),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(httpEntity),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(String.class));
    }
}
```

It is better to have the dependencies like `RestTemplate` or other `ServiceClass`es so that they can be mocked and tested easily.

Comment: ArgumentMatchers cannot be resolved, even when I add import statement

Comment: I am using Mockito 3.1.0 which comes within spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.2.RELEASE.
You can also try `Mockito.eq()`/`any()` instead of `ArgumentMatchers`.

Comment: I had to change my code a bit, now I have to use restTemplate.exchange Http.POST. I am getting error at `verification` statement  saying `The method is undefined for type MockitoAnnotations`

Comment: Okay let me try, is it possible to add an Assert here ? Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921249/how-to-mock-rest-api-in-unit-testing? Would you be able to figure out what changes do I need to make so that 401 error is being resolved? Is it because I am using actual url for POST? Thank you

Comment: If it is a unit test, you should test the method in isolation, therefore you should mock the request that is sent which means you should not make an actual POST request, and since RestTemplate here is a mock, you won't be able to do it anyway and about the verification part, please share the code you run.

Comment: I would be able to share code on stackbiltz, but not be able to run as there are many other files. Would that work for you?

Comment: Sure, let's try

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I wrote about [unit testing and test doubles](https://medium.com/@k.wahome/unit-testing-tell-your-doubles-apart-ddeb1aff44cc). You can have a read as a starting point on how to approach unit testing.

Some of it's key take aways are:

- Test Behaviour not Implementation. Tests that are independent of implementation details are easier to maintain. In most cases, tests should focus on testing your code’s public API, and your code’s implementation details shouldn’t need to be exposed to tests.
- The size of the unit under test is discretionary but the smaller the unit, the better it is.
- When talking about unit tests, a more quintessential distinction is whether the unit under test should be sociable or solitary.
- A test double is an object that can stand in for a real object in a test, similar to how a stunt double stands in for an actor in a movie. They are test doubles not mocks. A mock is one of the test doubles. Different test doubles have different uses.